# web2py hosting on google app engine and pointing to my own domain

Tags: hosting, dns, web-hosting, web2py

Can anybody suggest how to host a web2py app? I know that google app engine is an option, but if I use that can I make it show as my own domain? Any other hosting options better?

I appreciate the help

Jason

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can [use a custom domain](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/domain.html) with App Engine. However, [it won't work with SSL](http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/general.html#httpsapps), so any https URLs will have to go through your appspot.com domain. Note, although GAE is great for scaling and minimizing server administration, it does have some limitations that could affect your application architecture, so you should make sure it's suitable for your needs. See the [web2py book](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/11#Google-App-Engine) for details on deploying web2py apps to GAE.

Aside from GAE, you should be able to host web2py apps just about anywhere you can run Python, including many shared hosts. For VPS/dedicated hosting, I think a common setup is Ubuntu and Apache. See the [book](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/11) for deployment instructions, including pointers to some [one-step deployment scripts](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/11#One-Step-Production-Deployment).

For shared hosting, I've seen recommendations for WebFaction and DreamHost. For VPS/cloud hosting, I've seen recommendations for VPS.net, Slicehost, DreamHost, Rackspace, Amazon EC2, and a few others.

There's also a new service in beta called DotCloud -- [they offered to help put together a "web2py on DotCloud" tutorial](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/web2py/eRARkDuYGn4/VJ9twwOA3-cJ) (actually, looks like they now have a [tutorial](http://docs.dotcloud.com/static/tutorials/web2py/)).

Good luck. If you've got more questions, you should ask the [web2py mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/web2py) -- you'll generally get more and quicker responses there.